# Python permutations of a number

Tags: python

My code:

```
a = [1,2,3]
import itertools
set(itertools.permutations(a))
```

I get the output as:

```
{(1, 3, 2), (3, 2, 1), (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3)}
```

Can somebody tell me how to print the numbers like:

```
123
321
132
312
213
231
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Just so you know, you don't need a set.

Comment: There is not much 'so on' — three items make 6 permutations, so when you printed five of them there is only one to be added.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python get all permutations of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052951/python-get-all-permutations-of-numbers)

Answer (score 4):

Based on your code:

```
import itertools

a=[1,2,3]
permutations = set(itertools.permutations(a))

for perm in permutations:
    print("%s%s%s" % perm)
```

However you don't need to use `set` at all, so the solution (actually a better one) can be like this too:

```
import itertools

a=[1,2,3]
for perm in itertools.permutations(a):
    print("%s%s%s" % perm)
```

Comment: @kunal51, did you really use my solution as I posted it? You need to assign the set into the `permutations` if you want to do the first idea. Or use the second example I posted. It's better anyway.

Comment: @kunal51 it works for me, are you really trying exactly what I posted?

Comment: @kunal51, does it work now? Why are you deleting your comments?

Answer (score 1):

Cast the subelements to strings and then join them:

```
for perm in permutations:
    print ''.join(map(str, perm))
```