# Find all permutations of values in Spark RDD; python

Tags: python, list, apache-spark, pyspark, permutation

I have a spark RDD (myData) that has been mapped as a list. The output of myData.collect() yields the following:

```
['x', 'y', 'z']
```

What operation can I perform on myData to map to or create a new RDD containing a list of all permutations of xyz? For example newData.collect() would output:

```
['xyz', 'xzy', 'zxy', 'zyx', 'yxz', 'yzx']
```

I've tried using variations of cartesian(myData), but as far as I can tell, the best that gives is different combinations of two-value pairs.

Comment: how about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052951/python-get-all-permutations-of-numbers

Answer (score 1):

Doing this all in `pyspark`. You can use `rdd.cartesian` but you have filter out repeats and do it twice (not saying this is good!!!):

```
 >>> rdd1 = rdd.cartesian(rdd).filter(lambda x: x[1] not in x[0]).map(lambda x: ''.join(x))
 >>> rdd1.collect()
 ['xy', 'xz', 'yx', 'yz', 'zx', 'zy']
 >>> rdd2 = rdd1.cartesian(rdd).filter(lambda x: x[1] not in x[0]).map(lambda x: ''.join(x))
 >>> rdd2.collect()
 ['xyz', 'xzy', 'yxz', 'yzx', 'zxy', 'zyx']
```

Comment: This works for the given data set, but it appears it won't scale very well as I'm sure you're aware. Was looking for something that would still apply if I had say 10 unique letters. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> t = ['x', 'y', 'z']
>>> ["".join(item) for item in permutations(t)]

['xyz', 'xzy', 'yxz', 'yzx', 'zxy', 'zyx']
```

> Note: `RDD object` can be converted to iterables using
>   [toLocalIterator](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.toLocalIterator)

Comment: You don't need that `list` call, you can iterate directly over the iterable returned by `permutations`.

Comment: Hmm, this works outside of the scope of the RDD, but if I try it within the RDD pipeline I get the error "'TypeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object is not iterable". Example trys:

   test1 = originalRDD.map(lambda a: ["".join(item) for item in permutations(a)])

    test1 = originalRDD.map(["".join(item) for item in permutations(originalRDD))

I suppose I might need to settle for collecting first..

Comment: @HSskillet I don't know Spark, but that should work if you convert the RDD object that you're passing to `permutations` to a list or tuple. Also, you might be able to pass RDD.map a generator expression instead of a list comprehension.

Comment: @HSskillet, try converting your `RDD object` to `iterables` using `toLocalIterator()`

Comment: @JkShaw Best solution yet, although I suppose there isn't too much of a difference between this and collect(), but the use of an iterator appears more efficient than making a whole new list. Regardless, I am just parallelizing it again afterward. Thanks for the help!